# Why do people say that Java can't have an expression evaluator?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, reflection, java

I am aware that by default Java does not have the so-called `eval` (what I pronounce as "evil") method.  This sounds like a bad thing—knowing you do not have something which so many others do.  But even worse seems being notified that you *can't* have it.

My question is: What is solid reasoning behind it?  I mean, Google'ing this just returns a massive amount of old data and bogus reasons—even if there is an answer that I'm looking for, I can't filter it from people who are just throwing generic tag-words around.

I'm not interested in answers that are telling me how to get around that; I can do that myself:

#### Using Bean Scripting Framework (BSF)

File `sample.py` (in `py` folder) contents:

```
def factorial(n): 
    return reduce(lambda x, y:x * y, range(1, n + 1))
```

And Java code:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("jython");
engine.eval(new FileReader("py" + java.io.File.separator + "sample.py"));
System.out.println(engine.eval("factorial(932)"));
```

#### Using designed bridges like JLink

[image: example]

This is equivalent to:

```
String expr = "N[Integrate[E^(2 y^5)/(2 x^3), {x, 4, 7}, {y, 2, 3}]]";
System.out.println(MM.Eval(expr));
//Output: 1.5187560850359461*^206 + 4.2210685420287355*^190*I
```

#### Other methods

- Using Dijkstras shunting-yard algorithm or alike and writing an expression evaluator from scratch.
- Using complex regex and string manipulations with delegates and HashMultimaps.
- Using Java Expressions Library
- Using Java Expression Language
- Using JRE compliant scripting language like BeanShell.
- Using the Java Assembler and approach below or direct bytecode manipulation like Javaassist.
- Using the Java Compiler API and reflections.
- Using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` as root

Comment: What do you mean by Eval ? Do you mean taking a string math equation and calculating it ? Or do you mean taking a string line the should represent a line of code and evaluating that code in runtime ?

Comment: The [Terms of Service](http://corp.cheezburger.com/legal/terms-of-service/) for http://icanhascheezburger.com/ forbids reproducing their images. Image removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"eval" is only available in scripting languages, because it uses the same interpreter that runs the rest of the code; in such languages the feature is free and well integrated, as in scripting environment it makes little difference if you run a string or a "real" function.

In copiled languages, adding "eval" would mean bundling the whole compiler - which would defy the purpose of compiling. No compiled language I know (even dynamic ones, like ActionScrip3) has eval.

Incidentally, the easiest way to eval in Java is the one you forgot to mention: JRE 1.6 comes with Javascript engine, so you can eval any Javascript in two lines of code. You could even argue that the presuposition of your question is false. **Java 1.6 bundles a very advanced expression evaluator**.

Comment: AFAIK, jre does not come with a javascript engine, some jre providers include a modified version of rhino but it is not required.

Comment: @josefx, it's part of the standard API from 1.6.

Comment: "No compiled language I know has eval" - Lisp.

Comment: @Peter Taylor that is only true for the Scripting API, javascript itself is not required. See (JSR 223 impl.) http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/ ____________ Some people already ran into that issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649519/jvm-missing-rhino/4649839#4649839

Comment: @fdreger, @Peter Taylor - if you are referring to javax.el, I believe you are incorrect.  It is in Java EE, not Java SE.  (At least, that's what Java SE 6 javadocs say.)

Comment: @Stephen C: No, I don't mean EL, I mean Javascript.

Comment: @josefx: JRE specification does not include Javascript engine, but the standard JRE does include it anyway.

Answer (score 5):

As Daniel points out there is at least one limitation that eval-solutions face in java. The php eval for example executes the code as if it was part of the surrounding method with complete access to local variables, this is not possible to do in standard java. Without this feature eval alternatives require a lot more work and verbosity, which makes them a lot less attractive for "quick" and "easy" solutions.

`eval()` is mostly part of interpreted languages where the names of local variables and code structure(scopes) are available at runtime, making it possible to "insert" new code. Java bytecode no longer contains this information leaving eval() alternatives unable to map access to local variables. (Note: I ignore debug information as no program should rely on it and it may not be present)

An example

```
int i = 0;
eval("i = 1");
System.out.println(i);
```

required pseudocode for java

```
context.put("i",new Integer(0));
eval(context,"i = 1");
System.out.println(context.get("i"));
```

This looks nice for one variable used in the eval, try it for 10 in a longer method and you get 20 additional lines for variable access and the one or other runtime error if you forget one.

Answer (score 2):

Because evaluation of arbitrary Java expressions depends on the context of it, of variable scopes etc.

If you need some kind of variable expression, just use the scripting framework, and badamm! you have lots of different kinds of expression evaluation. Just take one kind like JavaScript as a default, and there is your eval()!

Enterprisy as Java is, you are not constrained to one choice.

Comment: You could map predefined variables that will be used in the eval expressions.

Comment: Also, that is not to say it's completely impossible. It's just grossly impractical. Not to mention that `eval` more often than not harmful or a crappy solution even in languages that support it.

Answer (score 2):

> But even worse seems being notified that you can't have it.

I think you are *misunderstanding* what (most of) those articles are saying.  Clearly, there are *many* ways to do expression evaluation in a Java application.  They haven't always been available, but at least some of them have been around for a long time.

I think what people are trying to say is that expression evaluation is not available as native (i.e. as an intrinsic part of Java or the standard libraries) *and is unlikely to be added* for a number of good reasons.  For example:

- Native eval would have significant security issues if used in the wrong place.  (And it does for other languages; e.g. you shouldn't use `eval` in Javascript to read JSON because it can be a route for injecting bad stuff into the user's browser.)
- Native eval would have significant performance issues, compared with compiled Java code.  We are talking of 100 to 10,000 times slower, depending on the implementation techniques and the amount of caching of "compiled" eval expressions.
- Native eval would introduce a whole stack of reliability issues ... much as overuse / misuse of type casting and reflection to.
- Native eval is "not Java".  Java is designed to be a primarily static programming language.

and of course ...

- There are other ways to do this, including all of the implementation approaches that you listed.  The Java SE platform is not in the business of providing every possible library that anyone could possibly want.  (JRE downloads are big enough already.)

For these reasons, and probably others as well, the Java language designers have decided not to support expression evaluation natively in Java SE.  (Even so, some expression support has officially made it into Java EE; e.g. in the form of JSP Expression Language.  The classes are in the `javax.el` package ... or `javax.servlet.jsp.el` for an older / deprecated version.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you already put the solution to your answer - bundle the BeanShell jar with your application (or lobby for it to be included in the JRE sometime), and you have your Java expression evaluator. It will still need a Binding of the input variables, though.

(What I'm more curious about: How does sandboxing of such a script/expression work? I don't want my web users to execute dangerous code in my server.)